# How do I rename files with list of names using command prompt?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, rename

I have a `.txt` file with a list of names such as:

```
george_washington
thomas_jefferson
meshach_browning
```

I want to use the names list to rename the `.xhtml` files within a directory.

For example: `00001.xhtml` would be renamed to `george_washington.xhtml`

I found [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27111496), by [rojo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1683264/rojo), and need some help to better understand it.

Would it be possible for someone to comment the script, so I have a better idea of how to modify it for my use?

For example: I do not see a path to the specified files, etc.

Comment: Please specify the problem better and what are expected results. I don't understand.

Comment: I would prefer it if you were to show us the full path to the parent directory of the `.xhtml` files, tell us the name and location of the `.txt` file, and explain to us how you intend to run this script. With those we can either offer an alternative or explain how best to use the linked answer for your specific case. It would also help if you told us how many lines there were in the file and confirm that it matches with the quantity of `.xhtml` files.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. The path will be: C:\rename_xhtml
The folder will contain the .txt file with the names and also all the .xhtml files to be renamed.
The files are here on Gdrive
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1uXMgCQ8vX5venvpfJgqpsQZrqVIAW7Is?usp=sharing

The hope is to rename all the .xhtml files with the names in the .txt file.
I hope this explains it more clearly.

Again, thanks.
WV-Mike

Comment: Open a command prompt window, run `ren /?` and read the short output help. Next run `for /?` and read the entire help displayed over several pages. The [solution posted by Aacini](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27112749/3074564) is even better than the [solution posted by rojo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27111496/3074564). In code posted by Aacini must be replaced `filenames.txt` by `"C:\Path\NamesListFile.txt"` or whatever is the fully qualified file name of the text file containing the new names for the XHTML files. The wildcard pattern `*.*` must be replaced by `"C:\rename_xhtml\*.xhtml"`.

Comment: Open a command prompt, run `ren /?` and read the short output help. Next run `for /?` and read the entire help displayed over several pages. The [solution posted by Aacini](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27112749/3074564) is even better than the [solution posted by rojo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27111496/3074564). In code posted by __Aacini__ must be replaced `filenames.txt` by `"C:\Path\NamesListFile.txt"` or whatever is the fully qualified file name of the text file containing the new names for the XHTML files. The wildcard pattern `*.*` must be replaced by `"C:\rename_xhtml\*.xhtml"`.

Comment: The command line `ren "%%a" "!name!"` must be modified to `ren "%%a" "!name.xhtml!"`. In code posted by __rojo__ must be replaced `textfile.txt` by `C:\Path\NamesListFile.txt`. The fully qualified file name cannot contain a space or one of these characters ``&()[]{}^=;!'+,`~``. Otherwise must be used `for /f "usebackq eol=| delims=" %%I in ("C:\Full Path\Names List File.txt") do (`. The wildcard pattern `*.doc` must be replaced by `"C:\rename_xhtml\*.xhtml"`. The command line `echo ren "!from[%%I]!" "!to[%%I]!"` must be modified to `ren "!from[%%I]!" "!to[%%I]!.xhtml"`.

Comment: I offer additionally a batch file solution with just one long command line which does not use [delayed variable expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) and works therefore even for XHTML file names with one or more question marks: `@(for /F "usebackq eol=| delims=" %%I in ("C:\Path\NamesListFile.txt") do @set "AA=" & for %%J in ("C:\rename_xhtml\*.xhtml") do @if not defined AA ren "%%J" "%%I.tmp" & set "AA=1") & ren "C:\rename_xhtml\*.tmp" *.xhtml` Please let me know if I should post this as an answer and explain it in full details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have not even attempted to code this yourself, here is an example of how I'd advise you to do it, but without any explanation or commenting/`REM`arks showing how it, or any of the contained commands, work. *(There are sufficient resources available within your Operating System, in books, or online, for you to learn these things.)*

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Set "DirXHTML=C:\rename_xhtml"
Set "FileGlob=*.xhtml"
Set "DirList=C:\rename_xhtml"
Set "ListName=name_list.txt"

(   For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('Dir "%DirXHTML%\%FileGlob%" /A:-D /B /O:N') Do (
        Set /P "BaseName="
        SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        Echo=Ren "%DirXHTML%\%%~G" "!BaseName!%%~xG"
        EndLocal
    )
) 0<"%DirList%\%ListName%"
Pause
```

All you should need to do is to verify that the information in lines 4., 5., 6., & 7. is still correct, as per your commented information. Save the script, (which should have a `.cmd` extension), with a suitable basename, and run it using whichever method you see fit.

Once you are satisfied with the information it outputs, all you need to do is to remove `Echo=` from line 12. and optionally delete the content of the last line.

---

Alternatively, you could just save the script to the same directory as your list and source files, verify that the information in lines 4., & 5. is still correct, as per your commented information, and use this version instead:

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Set "FileGlob=*.xhtml"
Set "ListName=name_list.txt"

(   For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('Dir "%~dp0%FileGlob%" /A:-D /B /O:N') Do (
        Set /P "BaseName="
        SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        Echo=Ren "%~dp0%%~G" "!BaseName!%%~xG"
        EndLocal
    )
) 0<"%~dp0%ListName%"
Pause
```

Once you are satisfied with the information it outputs, all you need to do is to remove `Echo=` from line 10. and optionally delete the content of the last line.

---

You will notice however that these examples bear a striking resemblance to the accepted answer in your linked question, and not the one you decided to choose. That is because, in my opinion, the `Set /P` method it employed is superior.

Please also note that this works on each file in alphabetic name order, your numeric naming matches alphabetically because each has the same number of digits. Should that change you will need make some not insignificant changes to the above examples.

Comment: Many, many thanks for taking the time to do this. I ran them both and they work beautifully. Looking over the batch files I get the idea of what each line does, but I could never have put something like this together.